# Set UIImageView on MainWindow to LandScape

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I want to set UIImageView to MainWindow. I have added UIImageView from IB. Whenever my app will start I want to show that imageView in Landscape orientation. I have tried to transform also but still not working. And once my app will start I want to give support for all orientation. I want to start my application in Landscape only. 
In info.plist I have set Initial interface orientation to Landscape (left home button) but still its not working. Any help?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Make your imagename `Default.png`.

Comment: I am using Default image only but still not able to do it

Answer (score 0):

You should make following changes.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
return YES;}
```

and set your imageview coordinate in  above method.and also you should change orientation in plist file I hope it will work. If any clarification let me know.

Comment: But we cannot get interface orientation in AppDelegate, so I cannot write shouldAutorotate function here.